# Low download speed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, download, bandwidth-throttling, high-traffic

Hey guys I am having a big problem and i need some advice .

I have a Dedicated server with those informations :

- Atom C2750 8/8t 2,4 / 2,6 GHz
- 16 GB RAM DDR3 1600MHz
- 12TB
- 500Mbps Bandwidth
- List item
- 1Gbps Network Burst

I am running a website using Nodejs where users can download high volume files .

The website evolved rapidly and I am having 10K users per day and an average of 1K concurrent users (downloads).

The problem is the server is getting lower and lower download speed on client's side so I have added a throttle to the downloads to 800Kb/s , it did help a bit but the problem remains the same what should I ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to figure out where your worst bottleneck is.  You will have to design some measurements and tests and maybe some calculations to help determine where the bottleneck is.

Here are some possibilities:

1. **Total server bandwidth over your server ethernet connection to the Internet.**  If you have 1K users all trying to download something and you have 500Mbps total bandwidth, then you're only going to get 0.5Mbps or 500Kbps per user.  At that point, you need to either shrink the data, reduce the number of users or increase your server bandwidth.
2. **Server CPU.**  This should be easy to detect.  Check your CPU utilization.  If your node.js process is using 100% of a CPU, then you are CPU bound and you either need a faster computer or if you have a multi-CPU processor, you can cluster your server on the same host to get more CPUs working for you.  If you don't have a multi-CPU process, then get one or cluster across multiple servers (the idea is you need more CPUs).  Though I have no idea if you are CPU bound (I suspect you're more likely bandwidth bound), this Atom C2750 has 8 cores so it would be good for clustering, but each core is not particularly fast compared to other Intel CPUs.
3. **Network card.**  It's possible that your network card could be holding you back and not fully saturating your bandwidth.  For example, if you only had a 100Mbps network connection to your server, then that's the max bandwidth you can use.  If you think you should have a 1Gbps network connection to your server, then you need to make sure you actually are getting that fast a link.

FYI, the 1Gbps Network Burst probably doesn't help you much if you have lots of users downloading stuff over a longer period of time.  That is most useful for a sudden and short peak of activity, not for a continuous high load.